Source for Hiddush on Parashat Bereshit
It says in Parashat Bereshit:
וַיְבָ֣רֶךְ אֹתָם֮ אֱלֹהִים֒ וַיֹּ֨אמֶר לָהֶ֜ם אֱלֹהִ֗ים פְּר֥וּ וּרְב֛וּ וּמִלְא֥וּ אֶת־הָאָ֖רֶץ וְכִבְשֻׁ֑הָ וּרְד֞וּ בִּדְגַ֤ת הַיָּם֙ וּבְע֣וֹף הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם וּבְכׇל־חַיָּ֖ה הָֽרֹמֶ֥שֶׂת עַל־הָאָֽרֶץ׃
God blessed them and God said to them, “Be fertile and increase
It is generally understood that the first words Hashem spoke to humanity are פרו ורבו , but this Shabbat I realized that the second Elohim is superfluous and had a Hiddush concerning this verse:
The first thing Hashem says to humanity is "Elohim" like it says in Psalms "Elohim Atem!" Meaning: You have the power to rule! And only then comes the Mitzva of Pru uRvu.
So the verse can be read as :
!"וַיְבָ֣רֶךְ אֹתָם֮ אֱלֹהִים֒ וַיֹּ֨אמֶר לָהֶ֜ם: "אֱלֹהִ֗ים
I am sure I am not the first one to have this idea. Can anyone tell me which commentary already said this?

R' Bachye says ויברך אותם אלקים was a distinct blessing that they should be immortal like Hashem, and אני אמרתי אלקים אתם is a reference to that blessing.

Similar reading on a different verse: אדם הראשון לא נצטווה אלא על ע"ז בלבד שנאמר ויצו ה'  "אלהים" על האדם (Sanhedrin 56b)

For your reading there should be a stronger pausal trope note on להם
